# group homomorphism into a module

Tags: group-theory

I have two (not necessarily finite) objects, both of which are groups.  Lets call them A and B.  I know that B is an A-module -- there is an action of A on B.  Does it then necessarily follow that there is a homomorphism of A into B?  There are lots of easy examples where this is true: let A be the integers, and B be the real numbers or the rationals, for example.  But is it necessarily true?  Are there any counter examples?  Basically I have strong reason to believe there is a homomorphism but because of the variety of possibilities for B, it is quite difficult to do a fully general proof that it is (or contains) a homomorphic image of A.

Ideas?

Based on the excellent answer of Matt S, let me add an extra wrinkle.  What if we do know that the action of A on B is given by the group operation of A?  In the problem I'm working on, B has to have the property that the group operation of A is 'supported', and this is the action of interest (there could be others, but that isn't known).  In other words, it isn't an action by conjugation...

Comment: Are you asking for non-trivial homomorphism? Otherwise just take $f(a)=0$ for all $a \in A$.

Answer (score 1):

This is false unless we allow trivial homomorphisms. For example, $\mathbb Z_2$ acts trivially on any group of odd order but there is no nontrivial homomorphism into the group. Less trivially, $\mathbb Z_2$ acts on $\mathbb Z_3$ by conjugation in $S_3$, and there is again no nontrivial homomorphism.

Comment: That's what I thought, Thanks Matt S!

Comment: @MichaelCloud you're welcome.